# Is there a proper way to use @PostConstruct in Micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm trying to print a message after the application startup with `@PostConstruct`, but nothing is printed.

```
package dev.renansouza.server;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ServerService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I have read that `@PostConstruct` is Lazy. Does this mean that I need to do
something else for this to work?

Comment: You have to do something to cause that bean to be initialized.  For example, inject that service into a controller and then send a request to that controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use `@EventListener` annotation to achieve what you want, if using `@PostConstruct` is not that important to you.

For example in your case, you can add the following code in any class to listen for application startup event.

```
@EventListener
void onStartup(ServerStartupEvent event) {
    println("Hey, I work from anywhere in project..")
}
```

> Code shared above is in Groovy

Keep in mind, the event listener added in main application class is usually called first from what I have observed.

Comment: Without knowing what he wants to do, how do you know that `@PostConstruct` isn't the right thing to do?  There are perfectly valid use cases for using `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: That doesn't mean we are not allowed to share the different approaches to the question.

Comment: Renan clearly states that he is trying to print a message on application startup, I answered on that part.

Comment: Also, I agree that I should have started with different sentence.

Comment: I assumed the message printing wasn't the actual requirement but was a way to help demonstrate the observed behavior.

Comment: Hello guys! Thanks for the fast reply. I'm building an application/microservice that will unpack compressed XML files and let them available to the next application/microservice. The main goal with <code>@PostConstruct</code> or <code>@EventListener</code> is to create the working directories. I thought about a controller to call a method from my service to do that, but the app will have a front-end that must know all folders. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're reading a large file or any potential long running task it is not a good idea to do it in postconstruct.

Answer (score 6):

The problem (aka feature) is, as you already mentioned, the lazy loading.

I see two solutions:

1. You have to do something to cause that bean to be initialized.
2. Change the scope of the bean from `@Singleton` to `@Context`

Micronaut has a few built-in scopes (see [https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#scopes](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Context.html)) and the documentation of `@Context` states (see https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Context.html)

> Context scope indicates that the classes life cycle is bound to that of the BeanContext and it should be initialized and shutdown during startup and shutdown of the underlying BeanContext.
>
> Micronaut by default treats all Singleton bean definitions as lazy and will only load them on demand. By annotating a bean with @Context you can ensure that the bean is loaded at the same time as the context.

```
package dev.renansouza.server;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Context;

@Context 
public class ServerService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzapostconstruct.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzapostconstruct/blob/master/src/main/java/renansouzapostconstruct/ServerService.java

```
package renansouzapostconstruct;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ServerService {

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renansouzapostconstruct/blob/master/src/main/java/renansouzapostconstruct/DemoController.java

```
package renansouzapostconstruct;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    private ServerService serverService;

    public DemoController(ServerService serverService) {
        this.serverService = serverService;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpStatus index() {
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

When you start the app you won't see the message printed to standard out because the service bean won't have been initialized.  Send a request to http://localhost:8080/demo/ and then you will see the message printed to stdout.

I hope that helps.